# Confirm box in asp.net web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to give user warning with confirm message box if they want to save without uploading image.

Code fires when user click on save button

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Image)) {
    obj.Image= null;
    //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('Please Upload  Image!');", true);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "confirm('Are you sure you want to save without uploading  images?');", true);
}
```

Above logic for was for showing confirm box but it doesn't show.

Besides that, how can I trap if user clicked on `Yes` or `No` button?

so that i can fire related code accordingly.

Update:

I am able to show confirm box with following code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msgbxConfirm", "confirm('Are you sure?');", true);
```

But i am not sure how i am going to trap the `YES` or `No`  event

Comment: You aren't in a function so you don't need the `return` statement - it is probably causing a syntax error, which is why the box is not showing

Comment: I had removed that earlier let me update question code.

Answer (score 3):

To handle the result of a confirm popup box - check the return value.

If OK is clicked it will return true, else it will return false.

EG:

```
if(confirm('test')) {
    alert('ok clicked')
} else {
    alert('cancel clicked or closed popup')
}
```

[JSFiddle example code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/dmcyhxx0/)

EDIT: comments

To resubmit the form if the user clicks OK on the confirm dialog something like this is what you need:

**Codebehind:**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "msgbxConfirm", 
    "doConfirm();", 
    true
);
```

**aspx page:**

```
<script type=text/javascript>

function doConfirm() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?') {
        document.getElementById(<id_of_form_submit_button>).click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is using java-script but how can i do it from code-behind file c#

Comment: What do you what to achieve? It looks like you're validating a form entry (file upload) using codebehind which would probably be better suited to a javascript check.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i am adding here, you can not get the confirm result in server side code, you have to write that code in JS side. So to maintain it in better manner, you can use following JS in aspx.

```
function ConfirmAndExecute()
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
    {
        OnConfirm();
    }
    else
        alert("you missed !")
}
function OnConfirm()
{
    // JS Code to handle post confirm operation
}
```

And in server side, page_load, use following.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msgbxConfirm", "ConfirmAndExecute();", true);`

Comment: That is fine but i need to check the the status in code behind. I think it can be done by setting the value in a hidden field & accessing value of this hidden field in code-behind.....

Comment: Yes, you are right! @KnowledgeSeeker, i thought of telling you `what can not be done`, that is why i mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just add an onclick client script event handle to prevent submission of the form unless the confirmation is true so you don't have to deal with the script registration. Just add the code below into your `asp:button` definition

```
<asp:Button id="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

Comment: Nice and easy .. thank you. Except I had to write:


<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Width="90%" onClientclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />


ie ... changed the OnClick to OnClientClick